# Weird behavior of parent and child in fork

Tags: c, fork, parent, sleep

After the execution of the below code, the root command line does not appear automatically. If the sleep statements are reversed, then the root command line is displayed.

Why this behavior?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    if(fork()==0)/*creating fork*/
    {
        sleep(10);
        printf("In child.. %d.\n",getpid());
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(5);
        printf("In parent.%d ..\n",getpid());
    }
}
```

Comment: I wager that the shell prompt *does* reappear, but before "in child" is written. I suppose the output you see is "In parent", "PROMPT#" and "In child", in that order.

Comment: Thanks Rob !!! Command prompt gets displayed only when parent execution completes?

Comment: Precisely. The command prompt appears when the parent process exits, even if a child process still exists.

Comment: Thanks Rob!!! Which is the best source to learn about signals from scratch?

Answer (score -1):

I wager that the shell prompt *does* reappear, but before "in child" is written. I suppose the output you see is "In parent", "PROMPT#" and "In child", in that order.
                    – Robᵩ